# Laravel 4 pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a question. How could I create subpages (something like this: character.php?name=Xar) but I want it in Laravel. Do I have to create routes? Also to mention, when I create a route like this:

```
Route::get('account/test', 'HomeController@test');
```

and the view is in folder under views/aac/test, and the function is like:

```
public function test()
{
    return View::make('aac.test');
}
```

it won't load the CSS. it's just an HTML page.

back to the problem again, how could I create sites like that? I'm also using Blade templating engine.

Comment: You should share the content of `acc.test`.

Comment: I made an example. Here's an route:

`Route::get('aac/test', 'SubController@test');`


Then the function in SubController:

    `public function test()
    {
       $account = Auth::user();
       return View::make('aac.test')->with('account', $account);
    }`

and then the test view:

http://paste.laravel.com/DJX

Comment: "it won't load the CSS. it's just an HTML page." It doesn't show anywhere that you are loading the CSS. So this is more important that what you have shown above.

Comment: @crynobone
that's what it won't load. that site that I've pasted into Laravel's paste service. it extends the base layout, and I'm loading the CSS in the base layout. here's how it looks: http://2.imgland.net/ZZWVZi.png

Comment: That why I'm asking you to include the page where you load the CSS. You are now putting code which is IRRELEVANT to your problem.

Comment: @crynobone

here: http://paste.laravel.com/DLV

Comment: found what's the problem, it loads the CSS from /aac/ but still there is no CSS files in that directory,they are all in the public file, image: http://3.imgland.net/OHwBjl.png

Comment: why don't you try blade syntax to load the css files like `{{HTML::style('css/you-css-file.css')}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// app/routes.php
Route::get('characters', 'CharactersController@all');
Route::get('characters/{name}', 'CharactersController@detail');


// app/controllers/CharactersController.php
class CharactersController extends BaseController
{
    public function all()
    {
        // show all characters
    }

    public function detail($name)
    {
        // find character by name & show detail for example
        return View::make('acc.test');
    }
}

// app/views/acc/test.blade.php
// HTML::style('css/style.css') loads CSS file located at public/css/style.css
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    {{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

**Search function**
Place search form somewhere in your view file

```
<form action="{{ URL::action('CharactersController@search') }}" method="get">
    <input type="text" name="search-term">
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

As specified, search form is submited to `CharactersController` and its `search` method.

Controller's method

```
public function search()
{
    $name = Inpute::get('search-term');
    $searchResult = Character::where('name', '=', $name)->get();
    ....
}
```

Register new route

```
Route::get('characters/search', 'CharactersController@search');
```

Comment: I want it to have like a search function, how could I make it like that? Like when I search it displays the best matching results and pulls the data out of the database?

Comment: how could I in the `public function detail($name)
    {
        // find character by name & show detail for example
        return View::make('acc.test');
    }` 

how could I find the character by name? I've tried doing something like $name = $player->name (I have a model called players, I've also changed Character::where to Player::where), what do I have to insert there? also, how could I display it in the view?

Comment: The below comment is too long. I'm doing something like this `public function search() { $name = Input::get('search-term'); $searchResult = Player::where('name', '=', $name)->get(); return View::make('aac.test')->with('searchResult', $searchResult); }` Also do I have to change the relations in the model toHasMany or something like that?

Comment: I think I answered your question and you accepted the answer. Why did you unaccepted it later? If you are trying to get my attention, you are doing it wrong - I may ignore you & your question instead.